# Having troubles with Webpack Dev Server settings

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

My project has roughly the following structure:

[image]

Webpack puts static assets in the `public` folder.

```
    output: {
        path: resolve('public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
```

What I would like to do is to make Webpack Dev Server serve `index.html` from the src folder, but to request static assets from the `public` folder. Is this possible? The docs say, put the `index.html` file in the build folder, but if the dev server can be set up to serve the static assets from the `public` folder, then there will be no reason to copy `index.html` in there as well.

I tried the following configuration, but it didn’t work:

in package.json:

```
webpack-dev-server --inline --history-api-fallback --content-base src
```

in webpack.config.js:

```
    output: {
        path: resolve('public'),
        publicPath: '../public',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
```

---

*Additional info, if it matters: I am also doing code splitting in my router, so that I get a number of smaller bundles (`0.bundle.js`, `1.bundle.js`, etc.) that are requested from the parent bundle (`bundle.js`) when the app switches to the corresponding route.*

*What I realized is that the main bundle creates links to the dependent bundles using the `publicPath` option of the the `output` parameter of Webpack config. In the example I showed above, the `publicPath` is `/`; so if I serve `index.html` from the `public` folder and `index.html` requires `bundle.js`, then `bundle.js` will require `0.bundle.js` from the same folder. If, on the other hand, I set `publicPath` to `/public`, then `index.html` placed in the `public` folder will have `bundle.js` that will require `0.bundle.js` from `public/public` folder.*

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to say that although I have not yet found an answer to my original question, I realized that an even better setup is to use `HTMLWebpackPlugin`, passing to it as a `template` option my `index.html`. The plugin will automatically reference my script files, add them into the template, and place the resultant html in the output path (`public` folder).

Couldn’t be happier with it!